# How to pass cucumber runner class in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have two runners file in my cucumber framework, 1. The main runner.java which executes all of my feature files and 2. FailedRunner which only needs to be triggered when the first runner reports any failures.

Now the current execution method I am using is

> gradle clean build -Denv=QA -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@QA

Now, I would Also like to pass my runner file name so that, I can create a upstream/downstream job to run the failedRunner class for retries for MainRunner file.

Thanks